# iOS B2B Distribution - How Apple will test a mobile app with privately deployed services?

Tags: ios, apple-vpp

One of our clients requested us to deploy the Mobile App in the B2B model. All App related services are deployed in the customer environment (a private network). Due to high confidentiality, none of these services are exposed to the public URL. According to Apple's standard procedure, Apple should review the app with one account credentials (login details provided by us) and will review all screens.
As I mentioned, all service URLs used inside the App are private network URLs ( Not exposed to the internet).

Then How Apple's review team will login in my app and do the screen review process?

Does Apple have any standard specification to review this kind of app? kindly advice.

Comment: Unless you can provide some environment for Apple to review your app they won't approve it. It sounds like the app needs to be developed as an enterprise app where review is not required. Be aware that enterprise apps need to be able to access the Internet periodically to verify that the enterprise program membership is still in good standing.

Comment: The only other approach you could try is to provide some credential that is hard coded into the app and that triggers a "mock data" mode where the app functions entirely using mock data built into the app rather than using network server data.

Comment: Thank you Paul for the reply. Around 6 months back one of our prime customers tried to purchase Enterprise Account for their organization, But Apple recommended Apple Developer Program and  B2B distribution model for deployment.

Comment: Yes, Apple does not recommend the enterprise program as it has been subject to abuse.  It is still available, but perhaps try my second suggestion.

Comment: Sure, for the time being second will be the right choice. But some of these apps are SSO based. SSO service may be hosted in the private network, in such cases how we will handle the login for review

Comment: Again, you can mock the authentication for review purposes or you can press your case for an Enterprise program.  This is really sounding like an Enterprise program app.